# Do I need to catch up on anything before watching Dragon Ball GT

Tags: dragon-ball-gt

Do I need to catch up on anything before watching Dragon Ball GT
or is it necessary to watch dragon ball Z before GT

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you need to watch Dragon Ball Z to understand GT. Watching the original Dragon Ball is also helpful, but not strictly necessary. If you want to skip the filler, you can watch Dragon Ball Z Kai instead.